# How to add skin effect to MenuItem in JavaFX 8?

Tags: javafx, material-design

I'm using a custom `Button` class that implements the effect seen in Android Material Design. I got this from [here](http://plumblog.herokuapp.com/2014/12/10/JavaFX-button-with-ripple-effect).

I would like to implement the same thing but in the `MenuBar` with `MenuItem`, but in this class I can't override `createDefaultSkin()`. Is there any other way to create this dynamic background? I have searched and only found how to change the background color or how to make animated transitions of colors but nothing like setting a custom shape like a `Circle` in this case that it's latter animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MenuItems are not controls, so they are not skinnable using the controls architecture methods like `createDefaultSkin()` - which you have already discovered.  You do have a few options though.

1. JavaFX supplies a [`CustomMenuItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html#CustomMenuItem-javafx.scene.Node-) class which provides a [configurable node content property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html#getContent--).  So you can customize the menu items by creating CustomMenuItem instances.
2. Standard menu items can also be customized by [setting a graphic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html#setGraphic-javafx.scene.Node-) on them.
3. Menu items can also be customized quite extensively without Java code by manipulating their CSS, though it would not be possible to achieve the animated effects in the android material design button you refer to.
4. MenuBars are controls and have a skin implementation, so you provide your own skin implementation for the entire menu bar (in the same way that the link you provided supplies a custom skin implementation for buttons).  The custom menu bar skin is then responsible for rendering the GUI of the entire menu and can do so using whatever implementation you decide to provide.

A menu bar is a far more complicated control than a button, so providing a custom menu bar skin is a non-trivial task.  To understand the built-in MenuBarSkin implementation, you can [search the JavaFX source repository for the MenuBarSkin class](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u40/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/MenuBarSkin.java).  The built-in menu bar can is complicated because it has the ability to use system menu features on a Mac, pop-up menus, scene graph node based menus within an app window, etc.  The built-in implementation handles some of the UI functionality for the menu bar itself and in other cases delegates to grabbing custom node content from menu items, various Java helper classes and ultimately the underlying OS windowing toolkit support for menu display and management.